Python "Explode" Keys in Dict
Given a dict like the one below how do I "explode" the keys to create a new dict with the keys split out? Each key should be split on " n ".
original_dict = {"AB n DC": [12, 13], "JH n UY": [22, 1]}

new_dict = {"AB": [12, 13], "DC": [12, 13], "JH": [22, 1], "UY":[22,1]}


new_dict = {k: v for orig_k, v in original_dict.items() for k in orig_k.split(' n ')}


Addendum: Note that all the v for the split keys are references to the same list; maybe use k: list(v) to create copies (depends on what exactly OP wants, but probably worth a note).

@tobias_k Yeah depends on the downstream operations with values.

Man, the python tag doesn't mess around in its speed. Beat me by a few minutes.

@ipodtouch0218 first time I get lucky to answer such a question at that speed :)

If you want to understand the logic, and don't feel comfortable using more complex python comprehension logic, the following code will give you what you need.
Start by initialising the new_dict as an empty dictionary, then iterate through original_dict and split on " n " to create the list of new keys.
Iterate through these new_keys and assign each to the original value from original_dict.
new_dict = {}
for key, value in original_dict.items():
    # Split keys on " n " or any value here
    new_keys = key.split(" n ")
    for each_new_key in new_keys:
        new_dict[each_new_key] = value

print(new_dict)


{kk: original_dict[k] for k in original_dict for kk in k.split(' n ')}

should do
But it must be noted that doesn't take into account the fact that if 'AB ∩ DC' is [12,13], then AB could be [12, 17, 42, 69, 13] and DC [12, 37, 99, 13]
Not to mention cases where your original dict is something like
original_dict = {"AB n JH": [12, 13], "JH n UY": [22, 1]}

So, my answer (and the other answer that came while I type) just ignores what n means, and just explodes.
